# Loop through Listiview items

Tags: vb.net, listview

I want to pass guid data in lisviewitem to the function called'GetPaymentLedgerByJobScheduleGUID', but I get the following error.

> Value type of listviewsubitem can't be converted to system.guid

```
For Each eachItem As ListViewItem In lstGroupPaymentDueCL.CheckedItems
    Dim Selected As Guid = eachItem.SubItems(7)
    Dim objPaymentLedgerData As PaymentLedgerData = GetPaymentLedgerByJobScheduleGUID(Selected)

 Public Function GetPaymentLedgerByJobScheduleGUID(ByVal guid As Guid) As PaymentLedgerData
    ........
 End Function
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you inspect what you get from `eachItem.SubItems(7)`?

Comment: I am getting 'f92c2457-1455-4db6-8147-301ca8d1ce6b' from SubItems(7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the Text property of the SubItem and Parse it

```
   Dim selectedGuidString As String = eachItem.SubItems(7).Text
   Dim parseGuid As Guid
   If Guid.TryParse(selectedGuidString, parseGuid) Then
       Dim objPaymentLedgerData As PaymentLedgerData = GetPaymentLedgerByJobScheduleGUID(parseGuid)
   End If
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Is Guid.TryParse a new tryparse method?

Comment: Available since 4.0 according to the docs.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx